# $_GET['id']; if value wrong

Tags: php, database, validation

I need to print a message if the `$_GET[id]` is not in database or do this code:

```
Header('Location:index.php');
```

Example:
If the people enter in this URL: `/index.php?id=100`
if there is no page "100" do:

```
Header('Location:index.php');
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer well without seeing whatever code you are currently using to access the database.

Comment: sample : http://www.lenszone.net/index.php?do=photoview&img_id=192

img_id=192  is OK
but when you change to wrong img_id LIKE img_id=1000
i want to do: header('location:index.php');

Comment: what code are you using to access the database **inside the PHP script**.

Answer (score 4):

Roughly:

```
<?php
    $imageid = (isset($_GET['img_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['img_id'])) ? (int)$_GET['img_id'] : false;
    if ($imageid) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE imageid='$imageid';";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if ($result) {
            // imageid exists
            my_image_display_function($result);
        } else {
            // imageid does not exist
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

**Update:** Edited to more closely match OP's table/variable names.

Comment: Note that `(int)$_GET['id']` sanitizes the input to prevent SQL injection attacks. That is why there is no need to escape it. (There's also no need to quote it.)

Comment: i'm Use this code for db :
 $imageid=$_GET['img_id']; $result_img = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE imageid='$imageid'");

Comment: @rixlinux: You're wide open to SQL Injection using that method.

Comment: @rixlinux better change it to `intval($_GET['img_id'])` or `(int)$_GET['img_id']`quickly, now your whole statement is 'in the wild', see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain

Comment: @rixlinux: The method I used above is probably one of the safest ways.

Comment: i did it, but it's same dont do : header function

Comment: @rixlinux: Then you're going to need to post the actual PHP code that you're using. Edit it into your question, rather than posting it as a comment.

Comment: @rixlinux: Looks fine. One thing to remember: You Can Not use `header()` if there's been ANY output (including whitespace) sent to the browser already.

Comment: if you have another idea for that tell me
look at :
http://www.lenszone.net/index.php?do=photoview&img_id=1911
no page but bad browse :(

Comment: @rixlinux: Until you post your entire PHP code, we can only guess.